# Stageros: how to programmatically set the pose of a simulated robot

Tags: ros, simulation, stageros, stage, player

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to know if it is possible to programmatically set the pose of a robot in stageros. Back when we used player/stage it was possible using the [simulation proxy](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Player-2.0.0/player/classPlayerCc_1_1SimulationProxy.html).

NOTE: my question is the same as [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/29562/how-to-i-set-a-robot-pose-in-stage/) but it has not been answered yet (altough the author marked it as solved - it isnt)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61503/stageros:-how-to-programmatically-set-the-pose-of-a-simulated-robot/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
Have you seen this another question http://answers.ros.org/question/12384/change-simulator-stage-model-configurations-in-runtime/ ?

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-04-26**:
it sounds promising, I will take a close look at it and I will be back here in some days, thank you!

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
Ok.. I'm looking for a way for doing so too... see you.

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-04-26**:
I have modified the stage driver to allow the reposition of the robots using a topic. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have modified the stageros.cpp file to make it subscribe to the topic "pose" which receives geometry_msgs/Pose2D and then sets the robot's pose to the desired one. The following are the lines that I had to add to stageros.cpp:

```
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h>

#define POSE "pose" 

std::vector<ros::Subscriber> pose_subs_;

void
StageNode::poseReceived(int idx, const boost::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::Pose2D const>& msg)
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(msg_lock);
    Stg::Pose pose;
    pose.x = msg->x;
    pose.y = msg->y;
    pose.z =0;
    pose.a = msg->theta;
    this->positionmodels[idx]->SetPose(pose);
}


pose_subs_.push_back(n_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Pose2D>(mapName(POSE,r), 10, boost::bind(&StageNode::poseReceived, this, r, _1)));
```

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
This is for one robot, isn´t it?

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-04-26**:
It is programmed exactly as the cmd_vel subscriber, so if cmd_vel subscriber is for one robot, this one aswell

**Comment by [kleinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22806/kleinma/) on 2016-11-11**:
I adapted your code slightly and submitted a pull request. It works well for multiple robots, just as cmd_vel. The one change I made was to call the topic cmd_pose to signify intent (write vs. read). The pull request can be found here: https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros/pull/39

**Comment by [kleinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22806/kleinma/) on 2016-11-11**:
Whoops. It looks like a pull request already exists for this. https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros/pull/27
The work is the `add_pose_sub` branch of the main repository.